# Hadoop's NameNode and DataNode Service did not run in single_mode

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I installed Hadoop 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 in single mode. But neither NameNode nor DataNode Services run after starting the Hadoop.

```
hduser@saber-Studio-1435:/usr/local/hadoop$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. 
Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
16/06/20 15:34:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-saber-Studio-1435.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-saber-Studio-1435.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 7214. Stop it first.
16/06/20 15:35:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
resourcemanager running as process 7374. Stop it first.
localhost: nodemanager running as process 7502. Stop it first.
```

Status:

```
hduser@saber-Studio-1435:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
8747 Jps
7502 NodeManager
7374 ResourceManager
7214 SecondaryNameNode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
First stop the hadoop $HADOOP_HOME ./sbin/stop-all.sh
Then format the hadoop ecosytem
./bin/hadoop namenode -format
./bin/hadoop datanode -format
./bin/hdfs namenode -format
./bin/hdfs datanode -format

Then start agian using ./sbin/start-all.sh

Then try jps on cli and if still does'nt works then remove the directory created for hdfs and recreate it using mkdir -p
```